# Hiding <TR> in IE7, jQuery UI buttons are still visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

This bug is driving me absolutely crazy.

I'm trying to filter a number of complex table rows using jQuery 1.4.4.

The rows contain `<input type="button" />` elements which are styled using jQuery UI 1.8.5.

This screenshot shows what the rows look like with no search filter applied.
[image: Correct Row layout]

These rows are dynamically added via an AJAX post call and are inserted after templating. This is the JS code for the post call.

```
$.post($.url('Asset/GetSites/'), { assetType: assetType, siteType: siteType }, function (data) {
    //hide the progress spinner
    $('.progSpinner').fadeOut();
    if (data.error) {
        ShowErrorBar();
        return;
    }
    $('#SiteRowTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo(tbody);
    $('#assetTable input[type=button]').button();

    //tbody.hide().fadeIn();

    //trigger a sort
    $('#assetTable').trigger('update');
    $('#assetTable').trigger('sorton', [[[0, 0]]]);

    $('#pageLbl').text(assetTypeName + ' Assets: ' + siteTypeName);
});
```

I'm then using a basic text input to filter based on the site and the description columns. This is where the issue arises. This is the code for that:

```
var rows = $('#assetTable tbody tr.assets-site-row');
rows.each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var id = row.attr('id');

    if (row.attr('id').toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1 ||
    row.children('td').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1) {
        //Search is a match
        row.show();
        $('#details' + id).show();
    }
    else {
        //Search is not a match
        row.hide();
        $('#details' + id).hide();
    }
});
```

In Chrome, IE8, Firefox, this works correctly. The rows that are not part of the search query are hidden correctly, but in IE7 things get broken.
[image: Failed table layout]

You can see that the jQuery UI buttons are not correctly hidden from view, for the rows that are suppose to be hidden. If I open up the developer tools and toggle the inline `diplay:none` style off and on the particular 'hidden' row, then the row hides correctly.

I'm basically at my wits end with this one. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had random issues like this happen in the past with dynamically added children. Basically I've had to call `.children().hide();` and then call hide on the parent. The best I could find was that the children elements were correctly mapped in the DOM of IE.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with.